# add the header in table and convert to flex table

Tags: r

I am trying to add a header above the table.

the objective is to add header above column name "#" and also I want to convert the table in flex table to apply flextable themes.

also i want to group the table on the basis of car type . any solution for that

```
df <- data.frame(names= c("Mazda RX4",  "Mazda RX4 Wag",    "Datsun 710",   "Hornet 4 Drive",   "Hornet Sportabout",    "Valiant",  "Duster 360",   "Merc 240D",    "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C",    "Merc 450SE",   "Merc 450SL",   "Merc 450SLC",  "Cadillac Fleetwood"),
                          score = c(21, 21, 22.8,   21.4,   18.7,   18.1,   14.3,   24.4,   22.8,   19.2,   17.8,   16.4,   17.3,   15.2,   10.4) )


table1 <- df %>% rownames_to_column("#") %>% rename("Car type" = names) %>% 
  mutate(score = as.character(score)) %>% 
  add_row(`Car type` = "", score = "form", .before = "#")
```

Comment: You get this error because `.before` expects a (numeric) row index. BTW: `dplyr::add_row` is for adding rows to a dataframe not for adding a header on top of the colum names. Maybe you want `flextable::add_header`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(names= c("Mazda RX4",  "Mazda RX4 Wag",    "Datsun 710",   "Hornet 4 Drive",   "Hornet Sportabout",    "Valiant",  "Duster 360",   "Merc 240D",    "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C",    "Merc 450SE",   "Merc 450SL",   "Merc 450SLC",  "Cadillac Fleetwood"),
                          score = c(21, 21, 22.8,   21.4,   18.7,   18.1,   14.3,   24.4,   22.8,   19.2,   17.8,   16.4,   17.3,   15.2,   10.4) )

table1 <- df %>% rownames_to_column("#") %>% rename(Car_type = names) %>% 
  mutate(Class = ifelse(score>21,"Top Class",ifelse(score>18,"Med Class","Low Class")))%>%
  mutate(Class = as.factor(Class))%>%
  group_by(Class)%>%
  arrange(Class)%>%
  select(Class,everything())%>%
  ungroup()
table1
```

I don't know if we can merge rows or even columns in R as you have done for Class. That is probably done in Excel.
You should group the columns and arrange them if you want something close to that

Also not sure about what you mean by header but if you want to change name of column you can use the rename function (Your usage won't work as there can't be any spaces otherwise it creates problem in referncing (It's a drawback in R, you should mostly replace whitespaces with . or _ before working))

Comment: I also want to add header above. as seen in above pic, "Form"

Comment: What do you meanby header. There is only colum names in R

Comment: for example in the desired output table, the is one header for names ("#", car,score) and above it there is another header required with names c("","",Form)

Comment: Ohh okay. I don't think we can do that. Also I don't see the need for it.